# Including django template with an incrementing context variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a simple template `destination.html`:

```
   <span>Name: <input type="text" name="destination_name_{{ counter }}"></span>
   <span>Rating: <input type="number" name="rating_{{ counter }}"></span>
   <span>Description: <textarea name="destination_description_{{ counter }}"></textarea></span>
```

I want to include this template in another template with a `counter` context whenever the user clicks an `Add` button. Naturally the counter I wish to pass will be an incrementing value depending on the number of times the user clicked the `Add` button.

I tried `{% include "destination.html" with counter = 0 %}` and this includes one instance of `destination.html` as expected, but I don't know how to increment the counter based on the number of times a button is clicked.

Comment: When the user clicks Add, do you post it to the server? Use a forloop.counter then. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for